# How to create conditional formatting based on individual user with (onEdit) function in Google sheets. (For every change)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for the script or code I need to enter in the Google sheets script editor, that will make any future edits made by different users, be shown in a different color. (Similar to how revision history works)

I have no coding expertise so if anything is unclear be sure to ask...

I've found some information myself and think I should use:

`onEdit` trigger and `Session.getactiveuser().getemail()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to select text within a cell and change it's color  programmatically.  I'm guessing that it's not possible even though it can be done with the editor.  But here's what I have so far and your welcome to take it and run with it on your own.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet1') return;
  if(e.oldValue && e.value) {
    var oldA=String(e.oldValue).split("");
    var newA=String(e.value).split("");
    sh.getRange('A2').setValue(oldA.join(','));
    sh.getRange('A3').setValue(newA.join(','));
    sh.getRange('A4').setValue(getChange(oldA,newA));                           
  }
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue('value: ' + e.value + ' oldValue: ' + e.oldValue)
}

function getChange(oldA,newA) {
  var oldA=oldA || 'This is the oldA'.split("");
  var newA=newA || 'This is the newA'.split("");
  var start=-1;
  var end=-1;
  for(var i=0;i<oldA.length;i++) {
    if(oldA[i]!=newA[i]) {
      start=i;
      break;
    }
  }
  oldA.reverse();
  newA.reverse();
  for(var i=0;i<oldA.length;i++) {
    if(oldA[i]!=newA[i]) {
      end=newA.length-i;
      break;
    }
  }
  newA.reverse();
  var rv=newA.slice(start,end).join('');
  return rv;
}
```

I've been using A1:A4 to get feedback information from the onEdit function.

Comment: Thanks @cooper. I wanted to try it but when I enter it, it says that the range of the sheet, as mentioned in the 2nd line of code  has not been defined.

The code I've found but I have similar issue with is this:
function onEdit() {
  var ss = sheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // GET EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);

  //HIGHLIGHT LAST EDITED CELL BASED ON OF ACTIVE USER'S PREDETERMINED COLOR
  sheet.getRange().setBackgroundColor(); 
}

But I have no idea if this code is valid/good.

Comment: This code cannot be executed without an event object.  So you can’t execute it from the script editor like any other function. It’s best to run as it was intended by simply editing the appropriate page.